# Swapping between WPF DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a WPF application where I have a small summary view for data but the user is able to expand that view up to a larger display.  The data content is basically the same so I was considering using the same view model for both.  Right now using MVVM the display of the data is governed by a DataTemplate.

How do I swap between Datatemplates for the same view model?  Is it even possible or do I need to create a ViewModel for the small view and expanded view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ContentPresenter` inside the "Primary" (notice the quotes) `DataTemplate`, and some `DataTriggers` to dynamically change it's `ContentTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                     Content="{Binding}"
                     ContentTemplate="StaticResource myViewModel1"/>

   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeVMProperty}" Value="SomeValue">
            <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource myViewModel2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

This way, when the `DataTrigger` is triggered, the `ContentTemplate` will be `myViewModel2`, and when it's not, it will be `myViewModel1`.